# How to show contacts from phone in an activity using tabhost

Tags: android, tabview

In my application i am using a tab view and in my first view i want to show all the contacts from my phone. How to get the contacts from phone and display them in an activity under tab view.

Comment: first of all, what have you tried so far? are you done with Tab display?

Comment: There are plenty of examples available to fetch contact detail.

Comment: yes, i have done the tab view and need to fetch the contacts in my first view activity

Comment: Dr. Nik has already provided a link, where you found exact code that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to get contacts from device

```
String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {Contacts._ID,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                Phone.NUMBER
            };

            Cursor c=managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String ClsPhonename = null;
                    String ClsphoneNo = null;

                    do 
                    {
                        ClsPhonename = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        ClsphoneNo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        ClsphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                        ClsPhonename=ClsPhonename.replaceAll("&", "");
                        ClsPhonename.replace("|","");
                        String ClsPhoneName=ClsPhonename.replace("|","");


                    } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
```

Then You can add all numbers and names in two arraylist and display in list in first tab

Answer (score 1):

This will help to you get contact list of your phone::::

[**http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)